# Error "Undefined symbol"?

Tags: iphone, opengl-es

I downloaded a code from http://iosdevelopertips.com/open-source/wolfenstein-3d-iphone-source-code.html

And downloaded file name is "Wolfenstein 3D for the iPhone". Basically it's a demo of 3D game. When that code i ran on machine it gave me some strange error are following
 **first “_GLimp_Shutdown”, referenced from:”
and ” other ” “_GLimp_AppActivate”, referenced from:**.

Comment: Does it happen if you build for the device? it could be a simulator issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Your code on actual device hope you dont get this problem...
OpenGL ES. OpenGL ES uses renderers on devices that are slightly different from those it uses in iPhone Simulator. For this reason, a scene on the simulator and the same scene on a device may not be identical at the pixel level. See “Drawing with OpenGL ES” in iPhone Application Programming Guide for details.”